# Javascript nested array to integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have a nested array

```
const folder = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6]]]]]];
```

please use the basic concept of javaScript.
I need return like 123456. what should I do?
i tried using for loops but it didn't work.

Comment: If it's always just one element nested each time, you can use a `while` loop.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#reduce_concat_isarray_recursivity

Comment: Yeah, use that `flatDeep` posted by @cmgchess and add `.join('')` to result..

Comment: or maybe `folder.flat(Infinity)`

Answer (score 0):

use the recursive function here.
find the below solution

```
const folder = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5, [6]]]]]];

let result = '';

function convert(arr) {
    arr.forEach((val) => {
        if (Array.isArray(val)) {
            convert(val);
        } else {
            result = result + val
        }
    })

    return result
}

console.log(convert(folder))
```